# how to use inlineshape addpicture function

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote the code below to add an image to header. I placed the .png file in a network file. The following code works in my PC, but not in a different PC which also has access to the same network drive. It does import the image into the header but throws an error at the (.addpicture) line as shown in attached image. Wondering why the same code which works in one computer is bombing in the other one. Appreciate any directions. Thanks

[image]

```
Private Sub AddHeaderToRange(rng As Word.Range)

Dim sFindText As String

With rng
    .Tables.Add Range:=rng, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2 'DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior, 
AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

    With .Tables(1)
        .PreferredWidth = Application.InchesToPoints(7)
        .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=0, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
        .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=200, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
        .Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=225, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone

        .cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture 
Filename:="\\srv2\gv1\eng\strss\Pics\Testlogo.png", LinkToFile:=False, 
SaveWithDocument:=True

        .cell(1, 2).Range.Font.name = "Arial"
        .cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Size = 12
        .cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .cell(1, 2).Range.Text = Sheets("Start").Range("P9").Value & " " & 
Sheets("Start").Range("P10").Value
        sFindText = Sheets("Start").Range("P9").Value & " " & Sheets("Start").Range("P10").Value
        .cell(1, 2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

        For Each r In .Rows
        r.Borders(wdBorderLeft) = wdLineStyleNone
        r.Borders(wdBorderRight) = wdLineStyleNone
        r.Borders(wdBorderTop) = wdLineStyleNone
        Next

        .Rows(1).Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalBottom
        .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        '.Rows.WrapAroundText = True
    End With

    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
End With

With rng.Find
.Text = sFindText
 If .Execute(Forward:=True) = True Then
rng.Fields.Add rng, _
         wdFieldEmpty, _
         "DocProperty TitleReference", PreserveFormatting:=True
   End If
End With

Exit Sub

eh:
Call Errorhandler("AddHeaderToRange", Err)

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells(1, 1)` not `.cell(1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
Activedocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture
```

After you fix that, you'll also get errors for the following lines that use .cell instead of Rows(1).Cells(1).

Comment: Activedocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(1) is same as Activedocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1)....Both works fine in my PC but not in colleagues PC. As i mentioned in my question, it does import the image but throws the error as shown in the attachment.